# Random Burst of CPU Act. in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount

On an hp 6730s(e) [32-bit]

Both cores of my cpu jumped to 100%, fans went up to full...

In a post for one of the previous versions...they had the same problem...

How do I mount the hard drive? and fix vgswap?

(How do I fix this)

-Ubuntu Noob

Answer (score 0):

> Both cores of my cpu jumped to 100%, fans went up to full...

Some CPU heavy background process probably ran. Probably candidates:

1. `updatedb`, which indexes your files for quick searching.
2. Any `apt`-related process, like `apt-check`. These keep your packages up to date and indexed. `update-apt-xapian-index` in particular uses quite a bit of CPU and IO.

Other timed tasks are typically not very CPU intensive. You can find then in the `/etc/cron.X/` directories.